# How to register after sheet (register) events in Laravel Excel 3.0

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I have used laravel excel version 2.1 previously . In version 2.0 cell designing was pretty easy . So  i started a new project in latest edition of laravel (5.5)
and was shocked to know that we can't use laravel excel version 2.0 in this version of laravel . I installed latest version of laravel-excel 3.1 and sheet styling is totally different from the version larave-excel version 2.0 so  i dig into documentation i found this custom macros to style the sheet but it didn't work.

**Here's the link for the laravel excel package being used**

[Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/getting-started/)

Here's my Export Class code

**Export Class**

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;

class CollectionExport implements WithEvents,FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize
{
    use Exportable;


    /*************** Alternate Method **************************/


    //  public function registerEvents(): array
    // {
    //     return [
    //         AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
    //             $cellRange = 'A1:W1'; // All headers
    //             $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);
    //         },
    //     ];
    // }

     public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeExport::class  => function(BeforeExport $event) {
                $event->writer->setCreator('Patrick');
            },
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

                $event->sheet->styleCells(
                    'A1:W1',
                    [
                        'borders' => [
                            'outline' => [
                                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
                                'color' => ['argb' => 'FFFF0000'],
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                );
            },
        ];
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return collect([
            [
                'name' => 'Povilas',
                'surname' => 'Korop',
                'email' => 'povilas@laraveldaily.com',
                'twitter' => '@povilaskorop'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Taylor',
                'surname' => 'Otwell',
                'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
                'twitter' => '@taylorotwell'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Name',
            'Surname__',
            'Email',
            'Twitter',
        ];
    }



}
```

**I'm calling this in a specific route**

```
return Excel::download(new CollectionExport(), 'export.xlsx');
```

This registerEvents method has no effect on the Excel file being created 
 Am I missing something or doing it wrong ?
Thanks in Advance !!!
P.S : - I have tried both methods for styling none of them effected the style of excel file

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that using:

```
-> use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
```